# Is there a way to use a for loop in a repr() function?

Tags: python

I want to print information on the status of the Nim game when its repr() function is called. However, I do not know how it will work without a loop in the repr() function.

```
class NimGame:

    def __init__(self, listOfNumBalls):
        self.listOfNumBalls = listOfNumBalls

    def __repr__(self):
        for num in range(len(self.listOfNumBalls)):
            return "Heap {}: {} balls".format(num,self.listOfNumBalls[num])
```

With a game such as "newGame = NimGame([1,2,3])",
I want it to return the following:

"Heap 1: 1 balls

Heap 2: 2 balls

Heap 3: 3 balls"

Comment: Yes, you can use a `for` loop, but you can't use `return` *in the loop* and expect it to still continue looping.

Comment: Instead, use the loop to build a larger string, and return the string you built.

Comment: What is the use case that you need this for?

Comment: You should probably be using `__str__`, if not some other custom method, rather than `__repr__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use `for`, like any other code, in your method. However, you have made two mistakes here: Firstly, [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) ends the call, so your code never repeats. Secondly, that's not what [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) is for:

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).

So the proper `repr` for your object is `"NimGame([1,2,3])"`, such as `"NimGame({!r})".format(self.listOfNumBalls)`.

The method you were trying to implement is more applicable as a `str`, something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join("Heap {}: {} balls".format(i,v) 
                     for (i,v) in enumerate(self.listOfNumBalls, start=1))
```

Comment: One nit: use a list comprehension, not a generator expression, as the argument to `join`, for a minor increase in efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If you return - you return. Any not yet executed loops of your for-loop will not be executed.

Construct the full string, return it:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self,listOfNumBalls):
        self.listOfNumBalls = listOfNumBalls

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join( 
            ("Heap {}: {} balls".format(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(self.listOfNumBalls,1) ) )


print( repr(T( ["b {}".format(i) for i in range(5)] )))
```

Output:

```
Heap 1: b 0 balls
Heap 2: b 1 balls
Heap 3: b 2 balls
Heap 4: b 3 balls
Heap 5: b 4 balls
```

Answer (score 0):

The "return" statement ends a block of code. So, your repr() function only runs once. Instead, you can append it to a string and return it after the for loop, like this:

```
class NimGame:

    def __init__(self, listOfNumBalls):
        self.listOfNumBalls = listOfNumBalls

    def __repr__(self):
        returnval = ""
        for num in range(len(self.listOfNumBalls)):
            returnval += "Heap {}: {} balls".format(num + 1,self.listOfNumBalls[num]) + "\n"
        return returnval
```

This will show your expected output when printed.